# Answering an old question that has an accepted answer

Tags: discussion, answers, late-answers

Is there an accepted way of answering an old (3 years) question that has an accepted answer that I think is incorrect or giving misinformation?

Are comments to the answer the way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As long as you are adding something new, it's not really a problem to make a new answer. You can also mention why other answers are incorrect in your answer, though try to avoid phrases like "The answer above" as the order can change.

You can also put a comment on the "wrong" answer as well.

It is easy to change the accepted answer from one to another, but if the user that asked the question hasn't returned to the site in 3 years don't expect your answer to become "accepted".

Comment: In addition, if you think that another answer is truly wrong (not just worded differently or not explained as well as you think you can explain it, etc), then go ahead and downvote it.  Downvoting competing answers shouldn't be done lightly, but when another answer is just plain wrong, or in rare cases, complete gibberish, it's your duty to downvote it.

Comment: Another option, if another answer is simply wrong, is instead of adding a "competing" answer would be to go in and edit the wrong answer and make it correct.